# encoding focus on specific object in video or quadrant of video

Tags: video, encoding, compression

I'm wondering about encoding that would focus it's data on a specific object in the scene, or a quadrant of the video.

Meaning after the encode, the bottom-left corner of the video capture is super accurate and everything else is blocky.  Or an object actor is in focus to sharp detail and the rest of the encode is blocky or blurrier.

Anyone ever come across such a project?

Answer (score 0):

What you are interested in is probably one of the following topics:

- Motion detection
- Spacial Redundancy
- Macroblocks

Besides wikipedia's [Video Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression) entry, always a decent source, I found [this presentation](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/~nimrod/Compression/Video/V2conspt2009.pdf) that might be more palatable for a quick overview on the different techniques that you are interested in.